# Tracking down a strange apache rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

The tl:dr; **How would you go about tracking down a url rewrite that should not be happening?**

---

The details:
I have one .htaccess file and it is simply:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Rewrite is enabled. When I visit a url like the following:

`foo.com/index.php` I get what I expect.
`foo.com/index/` however will redirect to `foo.com/index.htm`

So in my app route like `foo.com/index/books/fiction` will become `foo.com/index.htm/books/fiction`

Where could this be getting set? I thought it could be in my vhosts file but that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
etc...
```

which looks pretty vanilla to me. I then though is could be my DirectoryIndex (located in apache2's mods-enabled directory) needed to be specified so I changed that to:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>

          DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html

</IfModule>
```

But no luck. I'm not sure where else to look. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate debug logging in your logging environment and call that URL. Apache should create a detailed log where it went down the road. At least that's what nginx does in debug mode.

I have no clue why this is happening, but you could try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Instead of your rewrite which checks the other way around. MultiViews could also be a problem.